802.3-2022 MAC frame vs Ethernet Frame
I was looking through the 802.3-2022 standard for a project and I found something that confuses me. For context, the standard defines a "MAC Frame" as "MAC frame: Consists of the Destination Address, Source Address, Length/Type field, MAC Client Data, Pad (if required), and Frame Check Sequence." (1.4.385)
It also defines three types of MAC Frames: Basic, Dot1Q-tagged and Envelope, the difference between these being strictly the size of the MAC Data field, and implicitly, of the whole frame.
All clear so far, however, there is a statement that confused me:
All three frame types use the same Ethernet frame format. (3.1 MAC frame and packet specification. Overview)
What is this about? I thought MAC Frame is simply the 'official' name for the Ethernet frame, but given the statement above, it seems the standard differentiates between a MAC Frame and an Ethernet Frame. What is this difference? In which context MAC Frame and Ethernet Frame can not be used interchangeably?

I don't know what exactly they're trying to differentiate. To my understanding, there's just "payload", and that can be anything. If you go back far enough, there's a difference between "type" and "length", but just about everything these days uses "type".

"MAC frame" and "Ethernet frame" can be used interchangeably, ie. the former is the more recent term and the latter is phasing out.
In contrast to older definitions, the maximum payload (SDU) size isn't a single, rigid value any more but allows for some adjustment, depending on the frame's extended purpose. The payload for the actual user data remains unchanged however, and the general format and all other fields are the same.
